# Calculating mean grades for deciles within a dataset with Python, grouped by another field

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

```
import pandas as pd  
import csv



df_orig = pd.read_csv('test_sample.csv')  
df_orig = df_orig[(df_orig['number']>0)]  
decile_stats = df_orig.groupby(pd.qcut(df_orig.number, 5))['number'].mean()  


print(decile_stats)
```

I'm trying to use python to calculate statistics for deciles of my dataset. I can calculate the mean of each decile using qcut, but I want to group my numbers by the values in a second column. This way the deciles are calculated and reported on values according to their value in the family column.

family  number
0    1000    0.04
1    1000    0.20
2    1000    0.04
3    1000    0.16
4    1000    0.08
5    1000    0.02
6    1000    0.02
7    1000    0.02
8    1000    0.64
9    1000    0.04

My desired output would be:

Q1 1000  0.028617
Q2 1000  0.105060
Q3 1000  0.452467
Q4 1000  2.644886
Q5 1000  141.749797...

etc. with each 'family' shown, 1000, 2000, 3000 in this case.

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `df_orig.head(10)`.

Comment: Thanks Corralien - I've added it as a comment above. The real dataset has 500,000 numbers, and about 60 codes in the family column. I also changed the 10 in qcut to 5, as that was causing an unrelated issue due to the small size of the sample data here.

Comment: The expected output is number of `family number x number of decile per family number` rows?

Comment: I've addded to the description, ultimately I want the mean for each decile, but for each family also. So long as I get those numbers I can work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
N = 3
labels = [f'Q{i}' for i in range(1, N+1)]
decile = lambda x: x.groupby(pd.qcut(x['number'], N, labels=labels)).mean()

out = df.groupby('family').apply(decile)['number'].rename('mean').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   family number      mean
0    1000     Q1  0.030000
1    1000     Q2  0.080000
2    1000     Q3  0.333333
```

Comment: Is it what you expect?